# MBP 2011 Fail GFX Passing Tests

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics

I'm having the issue that a lot of people have with their MacBooks. It's a MBP 2011 15" and it's suffering from the dedicated graphics failure. I get the lines down the screen, screen shifting, and completely shutting down as most people report.

I tried to take it to Apple for the recall by they said it passes their tests and does not qualify for the recall. I have images and video of the graphics failure occurring and sometimes it won't even boot.

I've tried running the Apple Hardware test but with the short test it reports everything is okay, despite their being red lines running down the screen during the test!

What can I do?

Comment: You COULD put the MacBook in a nice warm spot with little ventilation and run some graphics benchmark on it. Note I don't recommend this, if Apple says it isn't the hardware failing, I'd check the connections inside before taking any drastic measures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently brought a MBP 2011 15" that was affected by the dedicated graphics issue to an Apple Authorized Service Provider (because that was more convenient than taking it to the next Apple Store). When they ran the test, they didn't find a problem either and then told me that they would not do the repair.

When I showed them the photos that I had taken when the graphic glitches occurred, they said that that was enough evidence and then they repaired the MBP.

Did you show the pictures/videos of the problem to Apple? If you did, I would either go to an Apple Authorized Service Provider and see if they agree to do the repair or go back to Apple and try escalate the problem. If you have photo/video proof of the defect, I would hope that it should not be too difficult to convince them to do the repair.